# Calling a swing software's main function in an JavaFX will terminate the JavaFX software

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8

When I tried to call a swing program's `main function` in a JavaFX program, the swing program runs normally. But when I tried to close the swing program, the JavaFx program also terminate. What's the reason? How can I solve it?

This is the JavaFX program code :

```
private void initStartGameButton() {
    startButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if(!isPosValid()){
                return;
            }
            String[] args = {"" + axePositionX, "" + axePositionY, "" + boatPositionX, "" + boatPositionY};
            Game.main(args);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the Swing program code:

```
// The entry point of the game.
// This class loads up a JFrame window and
// puts a GamePanel into it.

package com.neet.DiamondHunter.Main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {
    public static String[] args;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //save the args list.
        Game.args = args;

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Diamond Hunter");

        window.add(new GamePanel());

        window.setResizable(false);
        window.pack();

        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

with

```
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Note also that you are violating [Swing's threading rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading). The action handler's `handle(...)` method is executed on the JavaFX Application Thread, and consequently you are executing `Game.main(...)` on the same thread. As documented, a swing `JFrame` can only be created and displayed on the AWT event dispatch thread. You should modify your swing application so that it properly follows Swing's threading rules:

```
public class Game {
    public static String[] args;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //save the args list.

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            Game.args = args;

            JFrame window = new JFrame("Diamond Hunter");

            window.add(new GamePanel());

            window.setResizable(false);
            window.pack();

            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setVisible(true);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Will cause the JVM to exit when the window closes. Per the [JFrame API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html):

> EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the System exit method. Use this only in applications.

Instead set the default close operation to something else, perhaps

```
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Per the API:

> DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide and dispose the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.

This will help clean up and release some of the resources that Swing uses.

Comment: It did work, but every time I closed the Swing program. There is a exception. Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.neet.DiamondHunter.Main.GamePanel.drawToScreen(GamePanel.java:117)
 at com.neet.DiamondHunter.Main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:77)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: @zhangzhimin: That's a totally different problem, and you need to fix that exception as you would any other NullPointerException. The heuristic for NullPointerExceptions is almost always the same: You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.